# Can't access Phpmyadmin page

Tags: magento2, php, nginx, mysql8

I have installed Magento 2.4.1, Nginx, Mysql8, PHP 7.4 and PHPmyAdmin on Debian 10 on ec2. I have done all the steps from this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-manually-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu
My domain is example.mgt.com and when i hit http://example.mgt.com/phpmyadmin i get: Whoops, our bad... I might have done something wrong in /etc/nginx/sites-available/phpmyadmin so nginx can't "see" phpmyadmin.

Can anyone suggest something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe [*not* installing phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin)?

Comment: Everything works fine without phpMyAdmin but it will be easier to manage the database and now i have already installed it and i want to make it run. Has anyone done it?